# Pushing new files in a new repository Git

Tags: git, repository

I'm new to git and haven't gotten the idea of the workflow fully. So I've created a repository on the github.com and have been able to push all the files from my computer. Now I've created a new repo on the github and created a new folder on my computer. Everything gets pushed from the new folder, but it gets pushed in the old repository, as opposed to the new one. How do I switch to the new repository? Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `git remote` to view and edit the upstream repositories your local repo is connectted to. To view current remote repos

```
>> git remote -v
"remote-alias" ssh://url.of.remote.repository/ (fetch)
"remote-alias" ssh://url.of.remote.repository/ (push)
```

Each repo has a `fetch` and a `push` address that are used to fetch from the repo and push to the repo respectively. These are separate to allow setups where the fetch happens over `http` but the push happens over `ssh` for instance.

Use `git remote rm alias` to remove an old remote repository and

```
git remote add "alias" http://url.to.new.remote
```

to add a new one (just replace "alias" with the actual alias you want to use).

When you do a `git clone` a new remote is added by default under the alias `origin`, this is just a convention and you can name the aliases what ever you wish.

You can have more then one remote repository and when you `push` just define which one you want to push to

```
git push origin /src/java
git push dev-tests /some/other/path
```

Comment: No problems - the name is Matti though, not Matt, and please do accept the answer that solved your question by clicking on the tick mark under the up/down vote buttons.

Answer (score 0):

To push from a different repo, you need to move to the path of that new project and type again:

```
git init
```

*for each new project you need to type 'Git init' again

Also, add the new repo of github as remote in the new project since the path of the new project

```
git remote add origin git@github:<Github user>/<project name>.git
```

*Replace with the appropiate