# can't push a new repo

Tags: git, ssh

I am confused while creating a new git repository and pushing it to a ssh based git server.

What I did:

```
mkdir knowledge_base
cd knowledge_base
git init
```

( create some files )

```
git add <some files>
git commit -m 'initial'
```

until here all is perfect

now a do:

```
git remote add origin ssh://gitzfrdh@ex/home/gitzfrdh/gitrepos/knowledge_base
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

error:

> fatal: '/home/gitzfrdh/gitrepos/knowledge_base' does not appear to be a git repository
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

Yes, I know that the repo did not exist. My idea is to push this new one.

Must I first create a bare repo on the server side?

EDIT:
If I execute on the server:

```
mkdir knowledge_base
cd knowledge_base/
git init --bare
```

and on the client again a:

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

all works.

But I think it is not the intention to have a full excess on the server? I am wrong?

I already read 
[Pushing new files in a new repository Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144512/pushing-new-files-in-a-new-repository-git)
[New git repository error on first push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582407/new-git-repository-error-on-first-push)

Comment: I fear that, you have to create a new bare repo in the remote first.

Comment: Quite crazy that I read now a lot of other answers and none of them shows the need of the manually creation of the repo on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is correct; however, the remote address must point to an initialized Git repository too. It's a one-time job, though

```
ssh user@host "git init --bare /your/project/git/my-project.git"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a bare git repo on the server so that the client git repo has somewhere to push to.

From your example, the add remote tells the client where to push its repo changes to, and expects there to be a repo on the server that matches the added remote.